# Bot Telegram/Telegraf: ordenar botones

Tags: javascript, nodejs, telegram

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo ordenar los botones, que uno esté en la primera linea, y dos en la siguiente por ejemplo, y tres en la tercera por ejemplo...

Gracias de antemano .

```
bot.command(['inversion','inversiones','Inversion','Inversiones'],(ctx)=>{
     
    
     
   //Para poner botones y el extra de parse HTML
   ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id,'<i>Estamos en</i> <b>construccion</b>',
   {
       reply_markup:{
           inline_keyboard:[
            [{text:"click me", url:"www.google.com"},
            {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
            {text:"click me", url:"www.google.com"},
            {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
            {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
            {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
            {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
            {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"}
        ]
           ]
       },
       parse_mode:"HTML",

   })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
bot.command(['inversion','inversiones','Inversion','Inversiones'], (ctx)  => {
//Para poner botones y el extra de parse HTML
ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id,'<i>Estamos en</i> <b>construccion</b>',
    {
        reply_markup:{
            inline_keyboard:[
                //fila 1
             [{text:"1", url:"www.google.com"}],
                //fila 2
             [{text:"2", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
             {text:"3", url:"www.google.com"},],
                //fila 3
             [{text:"4", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
             {text:"5", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
             {text:"6", url:"www.mediavida.com"}],
                //fila 4
             [{text:"7", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
             {text:"8", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
             {text:"9", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
             {text:"10", url:"www.mediavida.com"}]
            ]
        },
        parse_mode:"HTML",
    })
```

})

Comment: Por favor, [provee más detalles](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/156327) a tu respuesta, y lee [answer].

Answer (score -1):

```
 bot.command(['inversion','inversiones','Inversion','Inversiones'],(ctx)=>{   //Para poner botones y el extra de parse HTML   ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id,'<i>Estamos en</i> <b>construccion</b>',{
   reply_markup:{
       inline_keyboard:[
        [{text:"click me", url:"www.google.com"},
        {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"}],
        [{text:"click me", url:"www.google.com"},
        {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"}],
        [{text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
        {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"}],
        [{text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"},
        {text:"click me", url:"www.mediavida.com"}
    ]
       ]
   },
   parse_mode:"HTML", }) })
```

Comment: Ahora mismo, tu respuesta se queda muy corta, deberías incluir código para que sea algo más aceptable, de lo contrario me temo que tu respuesta es más un comentario.

Comment: Provee más detalles a tu respuesta: lee [answer].